# How to ask user for input when an exception has occurred?

Tags: python, exception, math

I am making a code to solve quadratic formula and need exception handling such that missing command
line arguments are detected. In the `except IndexError:` block, instead of exiting
the program you should use `input()` to ask the user for the missing input data. It doesn't work with the following code. Anyone have any ideas?

```
from math import sqrt
import sys

print('This program will solve the quadratic formula with given values, please enter below.')

try:
    a=float(sys.argv[1]) #first system argument
    b=float(sys.argv[2]) #second system argument 
    c=float(sys.argv[3]) #third system argument
    d=b**2-4*a*c #discriminant
    x1=((-b+sqrt(d))/2*a) #first solution
    x2=((-b-sqrt(d))/2*a) #second solution
except IndexError:
    raise IndexError(
        'Oops! Looks like you have not entered all values. Try again.') #request user input
    a=input(sys.argv[1]) #first system argument
    b=input(sys.argv[2]) #second system argument 
    c=input(sys.argv[3]) #third system argument
    d=b**2-4*a*c #discriminant
    x1=((-b+sqrt(d))/2*a) #first solution
    x2=((-b-sqrt(d))/2*a) #second solution
    
print(f'The quadratic formula with used a,b,c values gives two roots {x1:.2f} and {x2:.2f}')
```

Comment: You caught the exception and raised it again. Remove `raise IndexError`.

Comment: `sys.argv` is a list containing all the given command line arguments. If you didn't give the proper arguments when you launched the program, they won't magically appear once you try to handle the exception. Instead, look into using `input()` to interact with the user.

Comment: Once in the `except` block, you are done with `sys.argv`. You are asking the user for value directly. The simpler thing to do is just exit the program, and make the user pass the correct arguments in the first place.

Comment: Use the `argparse` module to handle command-line arguments (and errors related thereto).

Comment: _Before_ doing anything else, check the length of `sys.argv` and make sure the correct number of arguments have been provided, and if not, using `input()` to get them )or just print an error message and quit).

Comment: Issue is that my code is supposed to ask for user input if user fails to write in something as an argument, instead of exiting, how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I see several ways to improve with the original code:

- Statements following `raise` are never executed
- Conversion of string via `float()` may throw a `ValueError`
- If less than 3 arguments are supplied, then `sys.argv[n]` will throw an error
- You should revalidate re-entered input until it's correct.
- You shouldn't trigger reentry of correct values if later ones have issues.
- If your discriminant d is negative, `sqrt()` will throw a `ValueError`
- Make your code **DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)** by factoring out validation logic.
- You need some way to do output.

The following code fixes these by:

- Adding a validate method to be more DRY and validate input and handle `ValueError`.
- Process the 3 arguments in order via an iterator that returns '' if not supplied, which the validate method will handle.
- Test for negative discriminant.

```
from math import sqrt
import sys

print('This program will solve the quadratic formula with given values, please enter below.')

def validate(name, value):
    try:
        return float(value)
    except ValueError:
        new_value = input(f"Entered a value for {name}: ")
        return validate(name, new_value)

args = iter(sys.argv)
a = validate('a', next(args, ''))
b = validate('b', next(args, ''))
c = validate('c', next(args, ''))
d=b**2-4*a*c #discriminant
if d >= 0 :
    x1=((-b+sqrt(d))/2*a) #first solution
    x2=((-b-sqrt(d))/2*a) #second solution
    print(f"the roots {x1} and {x2}")
else:
    print("the equation has no real-valued solutions")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are raising un exception inside the catch block:

```
except IndexError:
  raise IndexError(
    'Oops! Looks like you have not entered all values. Try again.')
```

You can remove it and prompt the user this message using input() or something similar. for example:

```
except IndexError:

    a= input('Oops! Looks like you have not entered all values. Enter the value again.')
```